# Short circuit `operator<<` output in C++

Tags: c++

I have some code that is sprinkled with constructs like this

```
if(debug) {
    Output << "f1: " << f1() << "\n";
}
```

Now what I want to do is write a stream class `Debug` where I could write it like this

```
Debug << "f1: " << f1() << "\n";
```

If some global flag is set then this would generate output, otherwise not.

Now: this can be quite easily done by making `Debug` return a stream that goes to `/dev/null` which would swallow the output. The problem is that `f1()` still gets evaluated (and 'rendered' into a textual representation which might be even more expensive) which might be quite bad for the performance.

Now my question: is there any trick that allows the skipping of the 'evaluation' of

```
"f1: " << f1() << "\n"
```

completely if `Debug` decides that no output should be done? Similar to the short circuiting that C++ does for `f() && g()` where `g()` is not evaluated if `f()`is `false` (I seriously considered writing a stream class that uses `&&` as the output operator but from what I read short-circuiting is not done for overloaded `operator&&`)

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826554/standard-no-op-output-stream) from earlier today could have the solution.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Those questions still (possibly) evaluate the arguments.  I don't think this can be done as asked, unless you switch the  format to something like `DEBUGOUT("f1: " << f1() << "\n");`

Comment: @MooingDuck true. They only avoid the streaming.

Comment: this SO looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035840/lazy-evaluation-with-ostream-c-operators

Comment: @MooingDuck: Except the one using the [evil macro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11826787/204847).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is define this macro:

```
#define Debug_Stream \
if(!debug); else Output
```

This would make this:

```
Debug_Stream << "f1: " << f1() << "\n";
```

become equivalent to this:

```
if(debug) {
    Output << "f1: " << f1() << "\n";
}
```

But literally (plus whitespace for readability)

```
if(!debug);
else
    Output << "f1: " << f1() << "\n";
```

Comment: This will will be susceptible to dangling else mismatches.

Comment: @MarkB: can be fixed via defining `if(!debug);else Output`.

Comment: Good catch Mark. And thanks @ybungalobill for the suggestion. I've changed the answer to fix.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not adverse to a macro, and are willing to accept the syntax:

```
Debug( "f1: " << f() << '\n' );
```

it's pretty simple: just define something like:

```
#define Debug( x ) debug != NULL && *debug << x;
```

It's somewhat dangerous, however, since you can't take the usual 
precaution of putting the argument in parentheses.  (On the other hand,
I've seen it used in a number of applications, without problems.)  The
macro approach has the added advantage of allowing you to insert
`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` automatically, if you want.  Or to
conditionally suppress *all* of the code completely, by defining the
macro to be nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by creating a delayed-evaluator that wraps expensive function calls. Your stream would know for the delayed evaluator type it needs to call the referenced function but otherwise it no-ops it, preventing the expensive call. The no-debug stream knows that for your proxy evaluator objects to just skip the evaluation completely.

For example a call might look like:

```
Debug << "123" << delay(f()) << "456" << std::endl;
```

This does involve remembering to invoke the delay in your debug lines. It does avoid the need for macros which may or may not be a key issue in your case.